# Change Treelist and Multilist to TreelistEx in Sitecore on template

Tags: sitecore, treelist

I have used multilist or treelist fields in my Sitecore install. I recently got to know the difference between treelist and treelistex and want to use treelistex field on items to speed up loading of items. I want to replace all multilist and treelist fields with treelistex fields.

Can I make this field change on a template level and not affect the current data? Or is the existing data going to be lost?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe both of those field types store their values as pipe-delimited lists of IDs, so your  pre-existing data shouldn't be affected if you make that change. You can always test this by just adding a new field, selecting some data, and then changing it to make sure the data is still there.